# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS - in case when subqueries

Tags: sql, vba, subquery, exists, case-when

I am creating a program in VBA, which generates access file-s for different countries. Every country needs different segments in their access file, so I have to generate these files in a country specific way. 
My data is coming from MS SQL Server, and after inserting my SQL query to VBA, I got an ODBC error, so I decided to solve the problem on the SQL-side first.
The vba codes go through on the entity_id-s in the tbl_entity table with a for loop, (I have the countries in this table), and checks their entity_ID-s. Depending on their entity_ID, they will have the Segment_ID-s they require.

Here is my code in SQL:

```
select case when b.entity_id = 7 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 5, 13)) 
            when b.entity_id = 25 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 1, 13)) 
            when b.entity_id = 462 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 8, 13)) 
            when b.entity_id = 12 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 1, 11, 12, 13)) 
            when b.entity_id = 13 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 1, 11, 12, 13, 7)) 
            when b.entity_id = 24 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 1, 11, 13, 9, 10))
            else (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 13)) end  
from (select * from sclr.Tbl_entity where entity_id = 7) b
```

the select * from sclr.Tbl_entity where entity_id = 7 is part at the end is just an example, because the VBA version of this is going to look like:

```vb
strSQL = "select case when " & rsRecSet("Entity_ID") & " = 7 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 5, 13)) " 
            strSQL = strSQL & "when " & rsRecSet("Entity_ID") & " = 25 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 1, 13)) " 
            strSQL = strSQL & "when " & rsRecSet("Entity_ID") & " = 462 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 8, 13)) " 
            strSQL = strSQL & "when " & rsRecSet("Entity_ID") & " = 12 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 1, 11, 12, 13)) " 
            strSQL = strSQL & "when " & rsRecSet("Entity_ID") & " = 13 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 1, 11, 12, 13, 7)) " 
            strSQL = strSQL & "when " & rsRecSet("Entity_ID") & " = 24 then (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment, explanation from sclr.Tbl_Segment where segment_id in (4, 1, 11, 13, 9, 10)) " 
            strSQL = strSQL & "else (select Segment_ID, Segment_name as Segment from sclr.Tbl_Segment, explanation where segment_id in (4, 13)) end into tmp_segment from sclr.Tbl_segment c "
            '--ODBC CALL FAILED

            Set qsQuery = dbSet.CreateQueryDef("")
            qsQuery.Connect = ConnectionString
            qsQuery.ReturnsRecords = False
            qsQuery.SQL = strSQL
            qsQuery.Execute
```

As you can see, there will be a recordset value added to the when statements, and the selects should run based on that.
In VBA I receive an 'ODBC call failed' error, which is caused by the incorrect query, and in SQL I have 'Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.' error.

Can somebody advise on this please?

Comment: As far as I know, `when...then` is not SQL. It may be programmatic statements that can be executed on MS-SQL server, but not in an SQL query.

Comment: You can't do what you're attempting to do in case statements. Case statements can only return a SINGLE value as its going into a SINGLE column. You're attempting to return 3 values within each of those case statements and cram them into a single column. You'll need to re-write your query to break out each of those columns into 3 DIFFERENT case statements populating columns.

Comment: What is in *rsRecSet("Entity_ID")*? If you are running in a loop, please show the  loop. These two queries are not comparable as second uses a different `FROM` and runs an `INTO` action.